# Special characters in ggplot2 axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am hoping to get some quick help with adding a superscript "-1" after my grams symbol.  I am shooting for:
[image]

With my code below:

```
labs(y = expression(paste("Fe ("mu "mol g"^-{1}")")), 
       x = expression(paste('OM (%)'))) +
```

But it instead reads out a list of 93 describing my ggplot code. Can anyone please help? I have spent an unacceptable amount of time trying to figure this out, and so desperately want to move on with my day.

TIA

Comment: I don't think you need to bother with `paste()`. here. What about `labs(y= expression(Fe~(mu~mol~g^-{1})) )` or if you want the mu closer: `expression(Fe~(mu*mol~g^-{1}))`

Comment: Thank you kind stranger.  You literally just made my day 10x better, haha!